# Need to display catalog image not found rather than placeholder in magento

Tags: magento, placeholder

I have been stuck in a problem. I am using another server for image uploading. Let me elaborate on the issue first.

When I delete an image manually from the media folder, now placeholder image is getting showed up.

Initially

> catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/o/controlbar-white-small.jpg

After Deleting image manually

> catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg

My requirement is my store should still fetch the same image Url as was before deletion as image path in the database is still there.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve my issue . I am mentioning the solution.

go to OnePica_ImageCDN-1.0.9\OnePica\ImageCdn\Model\Adapter\Amazons3.php

Replace this

public function getUrl($filename)

{

```
    $type = Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure() ? 'url_base_secure' : 'url_base';

    $base_url = Mage::getStoreConfig('imagecdn/amazons3/' . $type);

    $filename = $base_url . $this->getRelative($filename);

    return str_replace('\\', '/', $filename);

}
```

by

public function getUrl($filename)

{

```
 $type = Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure() ? 'url_base_secure' : 'url_base';

 $base_url = Mage::getStoreConfig('imagecdn/amazons3/' . $type);


    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

    $productId = $product->getId();

    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

    $imageName = $resource->fetchOne("select value from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id=86 && entity_id = ".$productId);

    $filename = $base_url . $this->getRelative($filename);

    $filename = substr($filename, 0, -22);

    $filename = $filename.$imageName;

    return str_replace('\\', '/', $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a core magento behavior so that product without image will show the placeholder instead of a broken image, so unless you make a lot of changes to core image/helper in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php the only other way is to change placeholder.

Have you think about just change the placeholder image?

In admin, under System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders, you can upload new file.

> core_config_data table

Comment: Yeah, This is a default functionality of Magento, But due to using another Server for image uploading, i wish to make it independent of Images files in magento media. I followed the same concept you suggest and come to a very easy fix which I gather in 3 valuable days.